# Comment Thread Blowing Up

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

On this question:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132267/trigger-modification-in-salesforce

The comment thread has gotten *way* out of hand. Is there anything we can do to bulk resolve a comment thread like this? I flagged many of the comments as too chatty, and probably more of them should be removed and posted as edits to the original question.

I feel like I have seen mods on some other sites have the ability to move an entire comment thread to chat and remove all the comments in that thread.

Comment: Most of the comments are just the OP impatiently begging for people to do his work for him.  Most of the comments aren't displayed unless you click on the 'show 15 more comments'.  Is that enough? Probably not.  I'd say the issue with this one is the question, not the comments section.

Comment: Isn't the issue more with the Questioner rather than the question or comments.

Comment: Well, all of the comments I flagged for deletion got cleared out, so I think we ended up trimming it down pretty nicely!

Comment: For the record: yes mods can migrate comments to a chat conversation, that has been done on this site in the past too when appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer just to summarise the comments.

1. Mods can bulk convert comments to chat, so flag away
2. If some comments have merit but some are fluff, just flag the necessary ones, it doesn't take us too long to run through the list and click delete on each.